# Windows 10 - How do I test touch events without a touchscreen?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, touch, simulator

I need to test my Windows app using touch events but don't have a touch screen available.

Comment: Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe is no longer part of Visual Studio 2022.

If you need simulator then install Visual Studio 2019 and UWP feature.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe**

Located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\16.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe`

The Simulator has modes that allow for basic touch events using the mouse, as well as pinch-to-zoom, and 2 finger rotation. It simulates your current Windows machine so you can even open up your code in VS, run your app, and set breakpoints that would normally only hit when using touch events.

---

**Edit:** based on the comment of Luishg, you need to install both Visual Studio and the Visual Studio UWP package for the Simulator to be installed.

[image: Simulator]

Comment: This thing no longer exists?

Comment: @ПетърПетров Did the version number possibly increase? When I first posted this answer it was `14.0`, someone later added an edit to make it `15.0`. I don't have a Windows machine handy to test this.

Comment: It is 16.0 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Windows Simulator\16.0\) now with visual studio 2019.
The version was accordingly to the visual studio version in which you installed the UWP package. If you had 2017 it was 15.0. and so on backwards.

Comment: Does anyone know how to install Simulator.exe if it's no longer part of Windows 10?

Comment: @I.Step Just a guess but based on the comment of Luishg, try installing Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there a way to get this tool only, without installing VS or the "UWP package"?

Comment: @BigHeadCreations I have Visual Studio. I don't have this simulator (and can't find it in the store).

Comment: @BigHeadCreations But the"Microsoft Emulator" might be a newer version of the same thing.

Comment: @KeithThompson As stated in the comment of Luishg, you need to install the Visual Studio UWP package for the Simulator to be installed.

Comment: @KeithThompson The Emulator is a totally different thing. By using that, you are basically running another VM. For the Simulator, it shows in the path and works well after I install both the UWP package and the Visual Studio IDE from the Visual Studio Installer. I can't find it directly from the IDE though.

Comment: In case it's missing from the computer, use this:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.Client/

Comment: @BigHeadCreations I have Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 and for each the "Universal Windows Platform development" package installed, yet the simulator is missing.

Comment: @JustShadow any idea on how to use this package?

Answer (score 4):

**Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe** is [no longer part of **Visual Studio 2022**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/missing-simulator-in-drop-drown-in-visual-studio-2/1622690).

If you need simulator then install **Visual Studio 2019** and UWP feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually launch this from visual studio now:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-in-the-simulator?view=vs-2019

**Set the simulator as the target**

To run your UWP app in the simulator, select Simulator from the drop-down list next to the Start Debugging button on the debugger Standard toolbar. This option is only available if your app's Target Platform Min. Version is less than or equal to the operating system on your development machine.

[image: Running in the Simulator]

PS. mine didnt actually work first time I had to reboot my pc to get it working